# Is it possible to store the data in assets or raw folder which application download from server?

Tags: android, file, data-protection

In my app user could download the data files from the server and use it through the app.But I am getting a problem for the protection of those files.

As those files are very important I cant just leave them in device to be copied and edited. So the question in my mind are:

1.Is it possible to download data files and store them in assets or raw folder?

2.Is there any secure way that my files are fully protected in device without being copied or used by other app.

Those files consists of images and videos.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: #1 no, the assests and raw folder are set when you export the signed apk #2 do a search on here for encryption (I haven't started using it so I can't give no pointers, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save files in the raw or assets folders, but you can use an internal storage ([See documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)) which is accessible only to your app. The other benefit of doing it this way is that when the app is uninstalled, your files are removed as well.